# Adding values of multiple checkboxes together; displaying a sum at the end...

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to create a spry accordion menu with a checkbox in each panel. This panel directly relates to a number of college credits. When that checkbox is clicked, along with how many other clicked checkboxes, a sum should display at the end of the page for the label - Total Number of Transfer Credits.

Here's the site I have so far (live): http://webfro.gs/south/toc/

On this jsfiddle, you can see what I'm ultimately trying to do... http://jsfiddle.net/jlnewnam/dC8T2/

**Here's the HTML:**

```
<div id="course_id">
    <input type="checkbox" value="3" />&nbsp; ASP100<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" value="4" />&nbsp; COM104<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" />&nbsp; ECO202<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" value="3" />&nbsp; MAT111<br/>
</div>
<br />
<br />
Total Potential Transfer Credits: <div id='total_potential'></div>
```

**Here's the JavaScript:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var sum = 0;
    $('#course_id :checkbox').click(function() {
        sum = 0;
        $('#course_id :checkbox:checked').each(function(idx, elm) {
            sum += parseInt(elm.value, 10);
        });

        $('#total_potential').html(sum);

    });

});
```

You'll notice that as you click each checkbox, the sum of the total number of credits increases.

I can't seem to pull this off in the spry menu. I guess it's because each panel has it's own ID, and I can't figure out the separation I need to accomplish the goal.

Regards,

KT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice easy one....

This should work with your markup.

```
$(function($) {
    var sum = 0;
    $('#CourseMenu :checkbox').click(function() {
        sum = 0;
        $('#CourseMenu :checkbox:checked').each(function(idx, elm) {
            sum += parseInt(elm.value, 10);
        });

        $('#total_potential').html(sum);
    });
});
```

You just needed the right slectors

Comment: Nice job, Ian... I see where I went wrong with the selectors. I used #course_id where I should have used #CourseMenu. Thanks!

Comment: Now, can we take this a step further and add up the number of checkboxes checked? Then multiply that number by 5 and have the result displayed? Would a separate script have to be written, or can that be included in this script?

Comment: you can factor that in... number of check boxes checked - var chked = $('#CourseMenu :checkbox:checked').length , and you can multiply that by 5 where you put that is upto you ;)

Comment: Yes, with a little time, I had figured that out. Thanks again for everything. `$('#total_time').html($('#CourseMenu :checkbox:checked').length*5);` I slipped it in just beneath `$('#total_potential').html(sum);` and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#CourseMenu input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
        var sum = 0;
        $('#CourseMenu input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function(idx, elm) {
            if( $(elm).val() && !isNaN( parseInt( $(elm).val() ) ) ) {
                sum += parseInt( $(elm).val() );
            }
        });
        $('#total_potential').html(sum);
    });
}(jQuery));
```

First of all you have chosen bad selector for `checkbox`. Secondly I prefer using `change` event. It should work with `click` as well, but logically I think `change` is proper in this case. Also I have added different way of reading the `value` (since your already have jQuery included).

I checked it by pasting into JS console of your **website** (not jsfiddle), so it's tested, and works.

Code working with jsfiddle:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#course_id input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
        var sum = 0;
        $('#course_id input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function(idx, elm) {
            if( $(elm).val() && !isNaN( parseInt( $(elm).val() ) ) ) {
                sum += parseInt( $(elm).val() );
            }
        });
        $('#total_potential').html(sum);
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Also I have no idea how this can work: `$('#CourseMenu :checkbox')` as `id` of container on your website and in jsfiddle is different. You don't have `#CourseMenu` element in your jsfiddle...

You can simply check it by pasting this lines in jsfiddle:

```
alert('Proper fiddle selector: ' + $('#course_id input[type=checkbox]').length);
alert('Wrong fiddle selector: ' + $('#CourseMenu :checkbox').length);
```

As you will see second selector doesn't return you any checkbox...

Comment: I just checked your above code here: <http://jsfiddle.net/jlnewnam/dC8T2/2/> and it didn't work. How exactly did it work for you?

Comment: @KoldTurkee First of all as I have written - my code works with your website - not with jsfiddle. Second of all I have added condition in case when `parseInt()` will return `NaN`, because in this section *PHI101 Ethics in Contemporary Society* your checkbox doesn't have a value, and accepted answer's code will not work in this case...

Comment: @KoldTurkee I provided jsfiddle code as well, and also explanation, as this selector $('#CourseMenu :checkbox') is wrong...

Comment: I didn't realize I had the incorrect selector in there. You're right and it did work once I fixed it.